# Linguagem de programação diretamente com hardware

Tags: c, c++, característica-linguagem

Vou fazer aplicações que necessitam de uma ligação direta com o hardware, por exemplo, um mini-robô programável que recebe informações de um sensor e envia para a programação tratar e devolver a ação correta a outra placa ou circuito e etc. necessária de acordo com cada informação recebida. Qual seria a linguagem ideal? C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existe linguagem mais adequada, pelo menos não com esta descrição.

Existe a que resolve o problema. Se o hardware usado não aceita códigos escritos em C, ela não é adequada. O mesmo vale para C++. Em alguns raros casos pode ser que você só consiga fazer sua aplicação, ou parte dela, em *Assembly* desse hardware. Pode ser que a linguagem ideal ou mesmo única para esse hardware seja uma que o fabricante inventou. Pode ser Java ou C#, ou quem sabe Lua. Depende também da aplicação. E depende mais ainda de qual você sabe e domina.

Não é a toa que o [Lego Mindstorms NXT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms_NXT) permite diversas linguagens, tem até dialetos. Imagino que deva existir bibliotecas muito boas para acessar o hardware através da maioria ou todas elas, mas este é apenas um exemplo.

Sem conhecer tudo isto que eu apontei e talvez algumas coisas mais fica difícil dizer qual é mais adequada. E uma destas coisas só você pode responder. Qual você conhece bem e terá satisfação em usar? Há fatores políticos envolvidos?

Qualquer um que diga qual linguagem você deve usar estará sendo tendencioso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/84514/164719

Tendencioso ou não, a linguagem C é fundamental pra quem deseja se aventurar no mundo de sistemas embarcados rs

Principalmente em relação a performance, lembrando que o NXT faz parte da família da linguagem C. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages

Comment: Se eu fosse ele usaria Portugol... :v uahuehaue

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio por isso que certas respostas tem data de validade. Muita coisa mudou de lá pra cá. É claro que C é a linguagem mais usada nesta área, mas está longe de ser a única e não necessariamente a mais adequada. Não tenho como saber. Ir no *default* pode ser mais fácil mas não quer dizer que está indo na mais adequada. PHP e JS também faz, viu?

Comment: Alguém discorda e negativou, pena não saberemos porque.

Comment: So pra deixar claro que não fui eu que negativei rs, apesar de não concordar em 100%, existem pontos que concordo e alguns pontos que não concordo inteiramente.

Comment: Um outro exemplo legal seria, eu desligar o monitor através do C ou então aumentar e abaixar o volume do computador e etc... é possível isso?

Comment: Como eu falei, pode fazer qualquer coisa em qualquer linguagem, desde que o hardware tenha a linguagem e bibliotecas específicas bem implementadas. Como a pergunta é genérica, não sei dizer. Agora você está falando em computador, já é outra coisa.

Comment: A sua resposta tá ótima. Mas, não apenas a sua conclusão como a aceitação pelo AP apenas confirmam pra mim que a pergunta é baseada em opiniões: "Qualquer um que diga qual linguagem você deve usar estará sendo tendencioso."

Answer (score 2):

O Maniero está certo, mas como você disse "aplicações que necessitam de uma ligação direto com o hardware" de cara eu indicaria linguagens de baixo nível, pois essa é uma característica delas. Isso vai depender do sistema que você vai usar. Por exemplo: se for usar um microcontrolador PIC, onde os recursos são escassos, Assembly ou C são as opções. Mas se for usar um sistema mais robusto, dotado de microprocessador, com mais recursos, passa a ser interessante o uso de linguagens de alto nível.